# Passing data from code behind to ViewModel Maui

Tags: c#, maui

Have a small app that I would like to capture information from my code behind and pass it to my ViewModel. The ViewModel has access to a 3rd Party API, so I would send that data too. I don't know the best way to pass that type of information.
**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BlueRC.ViewModels"
             x:Class="BlueRC.Views.MainPage"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Connect to Bluetooth"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Command="{Binding BluetoothConnectClickCommand}"/>
        
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Text="{Binding ConsoleMessage}"
               x:Name="StatusMessage"/>
        <BoxView
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Color="Gray">
            <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated" />
            </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
        </BoxView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind
**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace BlueRC.Views;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    private double deltaX;
    private double deltaY;
    public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        deltaX = e.TotalX; // want to send deltaX to my ViewModel
        deltaY = e.TotalY; // want to send deltaY to my ViewModel

        if (e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Completed || e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Canceled)
        {
            // Capture the deltas and send the info over. Then reset them.
            deltaX = 0f;
            deltaY = 0f;
        }

        StatusMessage.Text = $"X: {deltaX:N}, Y: {deltaY:N} StatusType: {e.StatusType}";
    }
```

How can I send deltaX and deltaY to my ViewModel? If it was a matter of creating a RelayCommand and linking it I would have done that ages ago. PanGestureRecognizer doesn't contain the Command attribute for me to data bind to.

Any advice?

Comment: You could use the [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) to map the event to a command.

Comment: For simple sending just set a property of the viewmodel from code behind.

Comment: BTW do you know you can add a custom bindable prooperty by yourself like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.clickgesturerecognizer.commandproperty?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Create a public method or property on your VM and pass the value in

Comment: @ewerspej, the EventToCommandBehavior seemed very promising looking at the documentation. However within my xaml I am getting the following errors when I do this...
<BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                        EventName="PanUpdated"
                        Command="{Binding SOMETHING}" />
                </PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviors>
</BoxView.GestureRecognizers>

This is the error: The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'PanGestureRecognizer'.

Comment: You're missing the parent node for the `<PanGestureRecognizer>` around the `<PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviors>`

Comment: @ewerspej, Thanks for the suggestion. Here is what I am trying. Still getting stuck, sorry there is something that I am just not getting.
<BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer>
                    <PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="PanUpdated"
                            Command="{Binding CaptureFingerMovementCommand}" />
                    </PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviors>
                </PanGestureRecognizer>
            </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>

Comment: @ewerspej, here are the errors I am receiving.
The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'PanGestureRecognizer'.
No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Behaviors", or mismatching type between value and property.

Trying to search for some examples. Maybe the (xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit") didn't download correctly?

Comment: @SirRufo, "For simple sending just set a property of the ViewModel from code behind. " can you please show me an example or link me to an example? Having difficulty passing info from the code behind to the ViewModel. Hence my question. Feels like I am missing something simple.

Comment: @FifthCloud It would be easier if you just update the question in the process of finding a potential solution. Regarding your other question: You could add a method or property to the ViewModel and then set/call that from within your code behind. Just add the ViewModel as a private member and then do something like this in the event handler: `_viewModel.UpdateXY(x, y);`

Comment: Yes, both of you are correct. It just dawned on me that I did a facepalm moment. Appreciate the help, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting hold of ViewModel.

Two Possibilities:

1. ViewModel passed in to View's constructor as a parameter.
   Then store it in a local field, so can access it later:

```cs
public MyView(MyViewModel vm)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  VM = vm;
  BindingContext = vm;
}

private MyViewModel VM;
```

2. BindingContext is set in XAML.

```cs
private MyViewModel VM => BindingContext as MyViewModel;
```

Either way, to access:

```cs
  VM.SomeProperty = ...;
```

Comment: Yes as mentioned by others this is the right way to go. For some reason, I didn't see it at first glance. What I ended up doing is a mixture of your answer plus having a public event and firing it from the code behind and notifying the ModelView of the change. 

'''
public event Action<double[]> NotifyPanUpdate;

 public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext = viewModel;
        this.NotifyPanUpdate += viewModel.NotifyPanUpdate;
    }
'''